# Google Drive v3 .NET: how to download all chunks of a file

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I want to download a file from Google Drive. I made a program in C# that uses the official Google Files v3 client library. I am using this code, however it only downloads a single chunk of the file. How do I download all chunks of the file?

```
var url = new Url(opts.Url);
                using (var driveService = new DriveService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    ApiKey = (string)url.QueryParams["key"],
                }))
                using (var stream = File.Open(opts.OutputFile, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    string[] pathSegments = url.Path.Split('/');
                    var request = driveService.Files.Get(pathSegments.Last());
                    request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += MediaDownloader_ProgressChanged;
                    await request.DownloadAsync(stream);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look through [the v3 docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) I can't see anything in your example that's obviously wrong. If I was encountering the same issue I would copy the example code from the docs and see if I could replicate the problem and narrow down potential causes.

For example (combining your code and the sample linked above):

```cs
using (var driveService = new DriveService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    ApiKey = (string)url.QueryParams["key"],
}))

// Replace this with the value you're expecting from `url.Path.Split('/');`
var fileId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M";

var request = driveService.Files.Get(fileId);
var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
    (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
{
    switch (progress.Status)
    {
        case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
            {
                Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                break;
            }
        case DownloadStatus.Completed:
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                break;
            }
        case DownloadStatus.Failed:
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                break;
            }
    }
};

request.Download(stream);
```

Once `request.Download(stream)` has completed you will have a value in the memory stream that you can use to create a local file - hopefully with all the expected chunks.

If the issue persists it's then a case of trying to narrow it down further e.g. if you wrap the whole thing in a try/catch is an exception being thrown mid-download, or is the value of `url.Path.Split('/');` not what you expect at runtime etc.